# How can I cache the PGP unlock for unix pass when I am in the virtual terminal?

Tags: command-line, password-store

When I am running in the GUI, if I run the `pass` command to read a password such as `pass -c Email/FooBar`, a password prompt will appear for my passphrase. If I type my password, my password will be copied into the clipboard.

If I subsequently run the `pass` command to read a different password without logging out and logging back in again, I do not need to type my password again.

However, if I try the same thing in the virtual terminal `Control-Alt-F1`, I need to type my password each time.

**How can I make it so that I can type the password exactly once per login session in the virtual terminal?**

Comment: Try getting the `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable from your GUI session and setting it to the same value in your Virtual terminal. There's most likely a daemon running that stores the passwords and a `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is most likely how the client programs communicate with the daemon.

Comment: @PSkocik, The value is `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6xONvYE5r7`. I tried setting that variable in the Virtual Terminal but as expected that alone doesn't fix the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You `export`ed too? E.g., `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ASSRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6xONvYE5r7"` ? I'd also try setting and exporting `export DISPLAY=:0.0`. I think if it works in GUI pseudoterminals, these two exports should make it work in a virtual terminal too (while the GUI session is still on).

Comment: @PSkocik, I did export it. Trying the display now also. Setting `DISPLAY` simply makes it so I can't see the password prompt anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in experience between using `pass` in a console (what you call a virtual terminal) and within a (GUI) terminal has nothing to do with `pass`, but with the secret key management done for `gpg` (as used in the `pass` scripts) by the `gpg-agent`.

This `gpg-agent` is, in modern distributions automatically started with X. You can see this by doing `env | fgrep GPG_AGENT` from a terminal and one of the consoles. On my Linux Mint 17, this is done by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent`.

As the `gpg-agent`'s `man` page tells you:

> If  you  don't use an X server, you can also put this into your regular
>          startup file ~/.profile or .bash_profile.  It is best not to run multi‐
>          ple instance of the gpg-agent, so you should make sure that only one is
>          running: gpg-agent uses an environment variable to inform clients about
>          the  communication  parameters. You can write the content of this envi‐
>          ronment variable to a file so that you can test for  a  running  agent.
>          Here is an example using Bourne shell syntax:

```
     gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support \
               --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
```

The `90gpg-agent` mentioned above is actually smart and tests whether the `gpg-agent` is already running, but it defaults to using `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info-$(hostname)`.

If your distribution has a similar setup, then you should be able to add the above lines to your `~/.profile` (but be sure to use the PIDFILE matching with your X started `gpg-agent`). You should, in also be able to use the same gpg-agent from multiple consoles by re-evaluating the `.gpg-agent-info` file.

While trying to set this up, make sure you run `pstree | grep -F pgp-agent` to make sure there are not more agents running than you need, otherwise it depends on the environment whether "`pass`" asks for passwords agains and/or between different consoles